# Xamarin Forms Picker SelectedIndex 0 not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created the following picker:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding agentPickerNames}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" SelectedIndexChanged="pickerAgent_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectedIndex="{Binding agentPickerIndex}" TextColor="White"/>
```

Now when I set the agentPickerIndex to 0, nothing gets shown in the picker, but when I set it to 1, I get the second line of the list. The problem is that I need the first line to be shown, but like I said: "The index 0 doesn't get shown by default!".

How can I fix this?

Comment: I test my demo it worked as normal, I set agentPickerIndex to 0 in the ViewModel, it showed correctly. I do not get this error message. And the default value for Picker is -1, if you do not set any value. Here is running screenshot and code https://imgur.com/a/9vbsEbY

Comment: My Xamarin Forms nuget package is `4.5.0.495`, you can clean and rebuild your project, if this issue is still existed.